# NumPy - median filter debugging exercise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filtering

I'm working on an assignment that has me debugging the following code.

```
import numpy as np

def subtract_smooth(x, y):
    y_new = y - median_filter(x, y, 1.)
    return y_new

def median_filter(x, y, width):
    y_new = np.zeros(y.shape)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y_new[i] = np.median(y[np.abs(x - x[i]) < width * 0.5])
    return y_new

print(subtract_smooth(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]),np.array([4,5,6,8])))
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
line 13, in median_filter
    y_new[i] = np.median(y[np.abs(x - x[i]) < width * 0.5])
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 5
```

I get that we are filtering `y` and using `x`/`width` as a means of indexing `y` for the median filter operation.

I also understand that the error is because `x` has five elements so the boolean array created by the comparison operator does not match the size of `y`.

I can get the code to run by deleting an element of `x`, but it's clear to me this is not the intended fix because the output subtract-smoothed array is all zeros.

Despite me understanding what each line of code does, and how np.median works, and how median filtering works in theory, I cannot figure how `median_filter` function is supposed to work. From my online research I'm pretty sure it is using a "sliding window" method, but that is a wild guess.

Someone please explain to me how this code works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think a vector of zeros is wrong? Because from what I see, you have a sliding window of size 1 that you subtract to your original vector, so it looks like it should be all zeros. That being said, the code looks super confusing to me, especially the fact that x is an input with a simple range.

Comment: @Nakor Ya you're right. I need to look at y_new to see what the output of the median filter is. I think I may be overthinking this one.

Answer (score 0):

@Nakor's insight that I was overthinking this was all I needed.

The code structure also confuses me, but seeing as this is a debugging problem that wants me to handle a specific error code then my solution to this problem is to simply remove the last element of `X`